# Dynamically added code not responding to jQuery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have read several questions on this forum about this problem, but it still not work for me. All other buttons and clickable elements that are in the code from the beginning works fine, but not those element that is passed dynamically. Everything works when I run the page local, but online it's not working. What could be wrong?

This is part of the dynamically code: (The `data[i].id` comes from an Ajax request)

```
html += "<td width='20px'>" + status + "</td><td class='updateCompleted' data-id='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].text + "</td><td align='right' width='20px'><img src='icons/icon-remove.png' alt='remove icon' class='removeIcon' data-id='" + data[i].id + "'></td>";
```

I then add the code like this:

```
$(".contentList table").html(html);
```

And this is the jQuery to detect the click:

```
// Handle click to set row in list to completed
$(document).on("click",".updateCompleted", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    updateData(id,1)
    console.log("Test");
});
```

Comment: Your code appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/qLdsztLm/. The caveat being that I had to add a `<tr>` element to the appended row - I assume you just missed that from your question. I'd suggest you check the console for errors.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your comment but the console gives me no error indication. The Ajax request responds with status 200. Any idea why it works local and not online?